# How to select data from non-table in Firebird?

Tags: sql, syntax, firebird

I'm searching for the Firebird equivalent of:

```
SELECT 'abc' AS abc, 123 AS def, '20110101' AS dt
```

Whenever I do

```
SELECT 'whatever' as xxx
```

I get an  error message.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firebird, like Oracle, requires a table for a `SELECT`.

Usually, `RDB$DATABASE` is used for this purpose:

```
SELECT  'abc' AS abc, 123 AS def, '20110101' AS dt
FROM    RDB$DATABASE
```